# OpenJDK 17 Alpine Image

Tags: java, alpine-linux, openjdk-17

I am looking for an openjdk 17 docker image based on alpine.
It looks like we have got one here

https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/17-alpine/images/sha256-a996cdcc040704ec6badaf5fecf1e144c096e00231a29188596c784bcf858d05?context=explore

But the below repository shows its not ready for GA. So I wonder from where do the above docker image gets the source file.

http://jdk.java.net/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 7th image layer in that Docker container contains the command used to download the JDK, including:

```
downloadUrl='https://download.java.net/java/early_access/alpine/14/binaries/openjdk-17-ea+14_linux-x64-musl_bin.tar.gz'
downloadSha256='f07a1ac921333dafac1cd886ad49600ce143be7efebd32e1a02599a8a0829dd4'
```

So it uses an early access build.

Comment: Thanks @Robin. Noticed just after posting the question, it points to EA. I was looking for GA and not available it seems. Any idea why its not been out yet? I couldn't see any documentation around when its going to be released.

Comment: @enthusiast Why not build your own docker image. Looks like https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk17&jvmVariant=hotspot allows to download JDK17 for Alpine

Comment: Yeah. I used to build custom image based on Oracle OpenJDK. There is something still pulls me back to go for Adoptium or other vendors. I may be seeing this an opportunity to do it. Thanks very much for your help, Accepting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/amazoncorretto/17.0.8-alpine3.18/images/sha256-6e6f780411eae55e8dcb59391aa09dd778f0fa2c896f9c218961fdb7da52f485?context=explore

or

amazoncorretto:17.0.7-alpine on docker hub.